# How would I make a script wait for a element to load with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

So I have a selenium script that will automatically enter a series of numbers into a website, and the website will redirect the user to another website based off if the numbers match a PIN. However, the browser takes a short time to redirect the user, in which the next line of code would have already run and returned an error.

I was thinking something like this would work but it doesn't, I don't know why.

```
def checkElement():
    try:
        xpath = '//*[@id="name"]'
        print("Page is ready!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("failed")
        checkElement()
```

Comment: You have to use a WebDriverWait: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for WebDriverWait. You can add specific condition in it. Please find the sample code below.

```
first_result = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='name']")))
```